# C++20 custom class for combining std::osyncstream and std::cout together

Tags: c++, c++20

I would like to use `std::osyncstream` and `std::cout` in a multi threaded context without writing everytime:

```cpp
std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "my message" << std:endl;
```

What I want to achieve:

```cpp
streams::synced_cout << "my message" << std:endl;
```

What I have done:

```cpp
namespace streams {
    class _synced_cout {
    private:
        std::osyncstream synced_cout_stream = std::osyncstream(std::cout);

    public:
        template <class T>
        std::osyncstream &&operator<<(const T& value) {
            synced_cout_stream << value;
            return std::move(synced_cout_stream);
        }
    };

    inline static _synced_cout synced_cout = _synced_cout();
}
```

But nothing is displayed, what I have miss? Or does a simpler solution exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`osyncstream` is kind of like `unique_lock`: every thread needs to construct its own instance of `osyncstream` because there is no synchronization on access to the `osyncstream` itself. All it does is buffering output in an internal buffer and eventually transferring that to the wrapped stream (or really, streambuf). Only the transfer step is synchronized.

Having a global `osyncstream` is therefore entirely pointless. If accessed from multiple threads, that's a data race; if not, there's no point in using `osyncstream` in the first place.

The buffered output is transferred

- when the stream is destroyed or assigned to
- when `emit` is explicitly called on the stream
- when `flush` is called on the stream and the streambuf has `emit_on_sync` enabled.

A simple option would be to have a special type that creates a new `osyncstream` object when used with `<<`:

```
class _synced_cout {
public:
    template <class T>
    std::osyncstream operator<<(const T& value) const {
        std::osyncstream synced_cout_stream(std::cout);
        synced_cout_stream << value;
        return synced_cout_stream;
    }
};
```

When the returned temporary is destroyed, everything written to it will be transferred to `std::cout`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I edited my question and yes my usecase of `osyncstream` is under a multi threaded context, In my case your solution solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just "dry coding" here, but shouldn't something like

```
struct streams
{
    inline static synced_out = std::osyncstream(std::cout);
};
```

Work?

No need for your wrapper class or its `<<` operator overload.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried your solution but it doesn't display anything either

Comment: @loic.lopez [In my simple example program](https://godbolt.org/z/KGn4Mfnfc) it works fine. Perhaps you're doing something else which affects the behavior? Can you perhaps edit your question to include a proper [mcve]? In what environment are you running? How do you build the proggram? With what flags and options?

Comment: I have tried to make a reproducible example: https://godbolt.org/z/nKzjnWdro

Comment: I think I have a data race as @T.C. said above.

Comment: @loic.lopez That sounds likely. Anyway, I'll let this answer stay to show you don't need to overcomplicate things. ;)

Comment: @loic.lopez By the way have you tried making the `synced_out` variable `thread_local`? Just add the modifier first on the definition of the variable.

Comment: `inline thread_local static std::osyncstream synced_cout = std::osyncstream(std::cout);` also does not work, another thing I have think, Does is it possible that `std::cout` is not initialized when `static` variables are created?

Comment: @loic.lopez Static initialization order fiasco is definitely a point here. You could create a function which returns the `std::osyncstream` object instead? I still think you don't need to create a wrapper class or overload the `<<` operator.

Comment: If you want to have a long-lived `osyncstream` then it’s your responsibility to manage when the buffered output is actually transferred to cout. Otherwise it’ll just sit in the buffer.

Comment: Thanks again @T.C. for more explanations.